# Web Mail client helper not translating newlines in body of msg (mvc3/asp.net)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, webmail

Can somebody tell me why newlines are not being translated in the email message when passed in as the body of the web mail helper?

```
            string body = "First line here" +  Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine +
          "Here is a newline...";

                    WebMail.Send(
                        "myemail@mycom.com",
                        "Subject",
                        body, "myemail@mycom.com");
```

Output is all on the same line in the email message itself.  Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Default value for parameter isBodyHtml from send method is true that's why Environment.NewLine is ignored. If you'll set isBodyHtml = false it will work.

```
WebMail.Send(to: "mail@gmail.com", subject: "Test", isBodyHtml:false, body: "First line here" + Environment.NewLine + "Second line.");
```